# Obtener día inicial y final, a partir del número de la semana y el año?

Tags: php, date

Estoy usando PHP 7.01, Quiero obtener el día inicial y final de 2 semanas distintas pero del siguiente año (por ejemplo, el día inicial de la semana 2 y el día final de la semana 3), por ahora uso esta función para obtenerlos pero solo funciona en el año actual, solo ingreso las semanas que necesito y me devuelve las fechas que requiero pero aquí no puedo agregar el año.

```
  for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){            
    if($i==0){      # Primer dia
        $first = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01/01 +' .($semana1 - 1). ' weeks first day +' .$i. ' day')); 
    }   
    if($i==6){      # Ultimo dia
        $last = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01/01 +' .($semana2 - 1). ' weeks first day +' .$i. ' day')); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco, y añadiendo un poco de código, obtuve la siguiente solución, pero aún me falta optimizarla, podrían ayudarme?

```
function get_dates( $sem ){

$week = $feini = $fefin = ''; 
$fecha = (date('Y')+1).'-01-04';   #declaro una fecha inicial 2018-01-04 

$week = date('W', strtotime( $fecha ));     #obtiene la primera semana del año

while( $week != $sem ){  #mientras la semana obtenida sea diferente de la solicitada

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days', strtotime( $fecha ) ));  #suma 7 días a la fecha anterior   
    $week = date('W', strtotime( $fecha )); #Obtiene la semana de la nueva fecha

}    #cuando encuentra la semana solicitada, separa el año, mes y día

    $day = date('d', strtotime($fecha));
    $month = date('m', strtotime($fecha));
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($fecha)); 

    $nuevaFecha = mktime(0,0,0, $month ,$day, $year);  #Ingresa la fecha separada a mktime 
    $weekDay = date("w", $nuevaFecha); 

    $nuevaFecha = $nuevaFecha - ($weekDay*24*3600); //Restar los segundos totales de los dias transcurridos de la semana                    

    $feini = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 days', $nuevaFecha));  #obtiene el día inicial de la semana solicitada
    $fefin = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime('+7 days', ($nuevaFecha+7*24*3600)));  #Obtiene el día final de la siguiente semana solicitada

    $fechas = array( "feini" => $feini, "fefin" => $fefin );  #guardo ambas en un array

return $fechas; #Retorno el array      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código hace uso de las funciones `DateTime` y `DateInterval`, que están construidas para trabajar con fechas.

Se define una función que recibe dos valores numéricos: año y número de semana, la cual devuelve un array con dos objetos DateTime correspondientes al primer y el último día (lunes y domingo) de esa semana.

```
function get_dates($year = 0, $week = 0)
{
    // Se crea objeto DateTime del 1/enero del año ingresado
    $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $year . '-1-2');
    $w = $fecha->format('W'); // Número de la semana
    // Se agrega semanas hasta igualar
    while ($week >= $w) {
        $fecha->add(DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+1 week'));
        $w = $fecha->format('W');
    }
    // Ahora $fecha pertenece a la semana buscada
    // Se debe obtener el primer y el último día

    // Si $fecha no es el primer día de la semana, se restan días
    if ($fecha->format('N') > 1) {
        $format = '-' . ($fecha->format('N') - 1) . ' day';
        $fecha->add(DateInterval::createfromdatestring($format));
    }
    // Ahora $fecha es el primer día de esa semana

    // Se clona la fecha en $fecha2 y se le agrega 6 días
    $fecha2 = clone($fecha);
    $fecha2->add(DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+6 day'));

    // Devuelve un array con ambas fechas
    return [$fecha, $fecha2];   
}
```

**Ejemplo de uso**: queremos obtener el primero y el último día de la semana 22 del año 2019:

```
list($lunes, $domingo) = get_dates(2019, 22);

echo $lunes->format('D d/m/Y');    // "Mon 03/06/2019", lunes 3/junio/2019
echo $domingo->format('D d/m/Y');  // "Sun 09/06/2019", domingo 9/junio/2019
```

- [Manual de DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)
- [Manual de DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php)
- [Manual de DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Hola antes que nada muchas gracias por la ayuda, estuve probando la función y me di cuenta de que, de la semana que pusiste no es correcta la respuesta. El resultado que obtiene la función es de la semana 23. Probé con más semanas/años y comparé con un calendario que tengo en javascript y usé la pagina timeanddate.com. Analicé tu función y solo retiré el signo = del while, y eso es todo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola. Estoy usando el número de semana que devuelve la función `date('W')` de PHP... no debería haber el error de una semana que comentas. En cualquier caso, si te fue útil la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como "respuesta aceptada". Saludos!